# Looping through ManagedObject

Tags: objective-c

i'm trying to add a NSMutableArray into my newManagedObject. The problem is it seem to insert the same object two times instead of both objects inside my theLanguage array.

this is my code:

```
theLanguage =[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects: nil];
[theLanguage addObject:@[@"Danish", @""]];
[theLanguage addObject:@[@"Russian", @""]];


AppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
_managedObjectContext = delegate.managedObjectContext;

newManagedObject = (Language*)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Language" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

for (int i = 0; i <= theLanguage.count-1; i++)
{
    [newManagedObject setValue:theLanguage[i][0] forKey:@"LanguageName"];
}
```

The output of the theLanguage array is danish, russian
the output of the newManagedObject is danish, danish. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you really should be inserting either 2 `Language` entities or you need to be setting the value of `LanguageName` to an array. Looping over `theLanguage` and calling the `setValue:forKey:` method on the same newManagedObject would overwrite any existing value.

I assume you really want to do the following:

```
for (NSArray *language in theLanguage)
{
    Language *newManagedObject = (Language *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Language" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [newManagedObject setValue:language[0] forKey:@"LanguageName"];
}
```

Comment: This gives me this output danish, russian,(null)

why also (null) ?

Comment: Is theLanguage array really only 2 objects? Also, what code are you using to print out the newManagedObject array? I would really setup the debugger and walk through the code.